# Map slightly off-center with simple (cartesian) CRS and tilelayer in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, tiles

After several attempts, some tinkering and a lot of asking here, I got my fictional map running with tiles by setting up a simple custom CRS. 
Alas, the map is slightly off center. I got the feelig that fitToBounds does not really work and if I add setView it does not change anything either.

My map size is 1024x1024 so the map should fit nicely at zoom level 2, [but look for yourself.](http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/test/Kisandra_map.html)

The code looks like this:

```
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Conversion from (x, y) raster image coordinates to equivalent of latLng
    // Taken from Leaflet tutorial "Non-geographical maps"
    // http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var yx = L.latLng;

    var xy = function(x, y) {
      if (L.Util.isArray(x)) { // When doing xy([x, y]);
        return yx(x[1], x[0]);
      }
      return yx(y, x); // When doing xy(x, y);
    };


    var minZoom = 2;
    var maxZoom = 12;
    var img = [
      16384, // original width of image `karta.jpg` => x / ~longitude (0 is left)
      16384 // original height of image => y / ~ reverse of latitude (0 is top)
    ];

    /**
     * See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638887/leaflet-custom-coordinates-on-image
     * http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#transformation
     * 256 px * 2^4 = 4096 px
     */

    L.CRS.MySimple = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
      //                      coefficients: a      b    c     d
      transformation: new L.Transformation(1 / 48, 0, 1 / 48, 0) // Compute a and c coefficients so that  tile 0/0/0 is from [0, 0] to [img]
    });

    var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(img)];

    var map = L.map("map", {
      crs: L.CRS.MySimple, // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-crs
      maxBounds: bounds, // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-maxbounds
      minZoom: minZoom,
      maxZoom: maxZoom
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);  //this makes the map fit the bounds we defined

    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      bounds: bounds, // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#gridlayer-bounds
      noWrap: true,
      attribution: 'Your Map',
      minZoom: minZoom,
      maxZoom: maxZoom,
      maxNativeZoom: 6  //how deep the actual map tiles go
    }).addTo(map);

//Experimental Zoom Viewer

    var ZoomViewer = L.Control.extend({
        onAdd: function(){
            var gauge = L.DomUtil.create('div');
            gauge.style.width = '200px';
            gauge.style.background = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)';
            gauge.style.textAlign = 'left';
            map.on('zoomstart zoom zoomend', function(ev){
                gauge.innerHTML = 'Zoom level: ' + map.getZoom();
            })
            return gauge;
        }
    });
(new ZoomViewer).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I'd try adding https://github.com/ardhi/Leaflet.MousePosition and seeing if the coordinates from your custom CRS make sense (check that the tiles and the bbox coincide). Maybe you have an off-by-one error, maybe you wanted to use 1/64 instead of 1/48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@IvanSanchez is right (tested), CRS transform should be

```
transformation: new L.Transformation(1 / 64, 0, 1 / 64, 0)
```

because you have 6 zoom levels and `2^6 = 64`.

Comment: Always the little things... The 48 were from another test with lesser resolution and zoom level. I hate it when I have to come here with stuff I should have found myself. But after staring too long at the same code, I kind of turn blind apparently...